# Are EnvironmentErrors the only Python built-in exceptions with errno's?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Are EnvironmentErrors the only Python built-in exceptions with errno's?

This would include:

- IOError
- OSError
- WindowsError
- VMSError

Are there any built-in error codes for the other exception types (such as ValueError, NameError, TypeError, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason these have error numbers is because that's what the underlying operating system is providing - Python is just passing the information along to you (if you are curious, the listing of built-in error constants is available in the [errno module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#module-errno)).

For Python specific exceptions (SyntaxError, ValueError, IndexError etc.) there are no error codes, because the exception is sufficiently verbose - compared with IOError which could mean anything from permission denied, file doesn't exist to security profile exceptions.

Strictly speaking, `SystemExit` does have a code (because this is the exit status of the application), but generally it is not captured. You can also pass in a specific error code to this (and other built-in exceptions).